# Protect/unprotect sheet

Tags: excel, vba, protected

I built a small Excel tool that asks the user to input cost elements and spits out an output.

I created Lock and Unlock buttons that allow the admin user to protect and unprotect all sheets for editing purposes. I have a total of 10 sheets in the tool. The buttons work except for two sheets.

The Unlock macro unprotects all sheets except the Cost Inputs sheet.
However if I use the small piece of the code that unprotects the Cost Inputs sheet in the immediate window, it works.

```vb
Sub admin_unlock_Click()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Sheets("Home").Unprotect Password:="xxx"
  Sheets("Cover Page").Unprotect Password:="xxx"
  Sheets("Study Categorization").Unprotect Password:="xxx"
  Sheets("Cost Inputs").Unprotect Password:="xxx"
  Sheets("Price Indicators").Unprotect Password:="xxx"
  Sheets("Benchmarking Output").Unprotect Password:="xxx"
  Sheets("Output Sheet").Unprotect Password:="xxx"
  Sheets("Instructions").Unprotect Password:="xxx"
  Sheets("Glossary").Unprotect Password:="xxx"
  Sheets("Export to CRM").Unprotect Password:="xxx"
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The Lock macro protects all sheets except the Output Sheet.
It also does not work if I place the relevant bit of code in the immediate window.

```vb
Sub admin_lock_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Home").Protect Password:="xxx", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Sheets("Cover Page").Protect Password:="xxx", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Sheets("Study Categorization").Protect Password:="xxx", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Sheets("Cost Inputs").Protect Password:="xxx", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Sheets("Price Indicators").Protect Password:="xxx", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Sheets("Benchmarking Output").Protect Password:="xxx", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Sheets("Output Sheet").Protect Password:="xxx", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Sheets("Instructions").Protect Password:="xxx", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Sheets("Glossary").Protect Password:="xxx", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Sheets("Export to CRM").Protect Password:="xxx", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I would consider a sheet loop here if they all have a shared password. Also, if that is the case, why not just lock/unlock the book?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a sheet loop rather typing out each sheets name like so ~

```
Sub admin_unlock_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Unprotect "xxx"
Next ws

End Sub
```

```
Sub admin_lock_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Protect "xxx", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Next ws

End Sub
```

If you are locking every sheet, why not just lock the book instead? Then you only have to protect/unprotect the book rather every single sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your help urdearboy, but the loop does not seem to help :( I'll try protecting the workbook now.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that Excel has an issue with .Unprotect !

Using the assigned object to perform unprotect is unreliable, such as:

```
ws.Unprotect
```

This method *may* fail and can be a problem to resolve if not aware of the issue.

To be sure, unprotect the sheet directly (by name or number)

```
Sheets("MySheet").Unprotect
```

or

```
Sheets(3).Unprotect
```

Hope this helps DG

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although your answer seems to solve the OP problem, your answer will be more useful, and more easily upvoted if you provide a link any time that you say things like **Excel has an issue with .Unprotect**

Answer (score 0):

The `.Protect` protects the locked cells in VBA by default. Probably your worksheet does not have locked cells. As a workaround try this:

Create a new module in VBA.
In the new module copy and paste this:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Worksheets("Cost Inputs").Cells.Locked = True
End Sub
```

In the immediate window, write `TestMe` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Run your code again. Is it protected? If it is not, then you p`robably have On Error Resume Next` on your code.

Comment: Hi Vityata, thanks for your help, but I do have locked cells on the sheet that isnt being protected. As for the TestMe, it would lock all cells on the sheet which is not what I want (input cells must remain unlocked). What do you mean with the On Error Resume Next?

Comment: Do you have on error resume next anywhere in your code is the ask